# How to connect to an external service on a non-standard port from an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to access a third party service from Azure App Services (ideally Functions, but a Web App would do). However this service is hosted on a non-standard port, e.g. https://myservice.com:445

I'm using the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)  to make a POST request, but consistently get a `SocketException`:

> An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 1.2.3.4:445

The code works on my local environment (Functions emulator or Kestrel), but fails on Azure. I tried using a service hosted on a regular https endpoint, e.g. https://myotherservice.com, and the call goes through normally.

I'm assuming there is some sort of outbound firewall rule that's preventing the fist call, but I haven't found any configuration option to disable this. Is it possible? I unfortunately cannot change the endpoint of the service I need to call.

Comment: There is no restriction on Outbound IP addresses and ports. Are you sure the service itself doesn't have some kind of whitelist?

Comment: @Mikhail there is no whitelist, the service is accessible from the Internet. It does use a self-signed certificate though. I wonder if for some reason that might be the source of the exception...

Comment: Can you share your application name directly or indirectly (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) so we can rule out other potential issues? Does this happen consistenly? Or is it sporadic?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Thanks, this happens consistently, even after changing the server's certificate. Here an execution timestamp, hope it helps: 2017-07-10T09:42:48.934 Function started (Id=a51aeb14-dacc-46cc-9e8b-5539301b996f) (West Europe)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I added an answer with my findings below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your application, I did indeed find that those outgoing requests were being blocked by the infrastructure.

I was also able to find public documentation covering those ports here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports

Comment: 65531 ports available and we went with one of the 4 that don't work  This was definitively the problem, however I would've never found the docs that you linked, mostly on account of them not being on a Microsoft or Azure site. Thanks!